# What does bool(T::* ...) do?

Tags: c++, ros

From ROS 1's `node_handle.h`, a certain API is specified as:

```
template<class T, class MReq, class MRes>
ServiceServer NodeHandle::advertiseService(const std::string &service, bool(T::*srv_func)(MReq &, MRes &), T* obj)
```

`srv_func` is a callback for this service, `MReq` is a request class, `MRes` is a result class. `obj` is because this is a class member version of the callback.

Can someone please explain what this syntax `bool(T::*...` means? Is it just enforcing that `srv_func` must be a class member of `T`, as opposed to any old function?

Comment: That's a pointer to a memberfunction. The following parentheses contain the parameters the memberfunction takes, the return type is `bool`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> template<class T, class MReq, class MRes> ServiceServer NodeHandle::advertiseService(const std::string &service, bool(T::*srv_func)(MReq &, MRes &), T* obj)
> ```

This is a function template. `T`, `MReq` and `MRes` are template type parameters of the template.

> ```
> (const std::string &service, bool(T::*srv_func)(MReq &, MRes &), T* obj)
> ```

This is the parameter list of the function template

> ```
> bool(T::*srv_func)(MReq &, MRes &)
> ```

This is the second parameter of the function template.

The name of the parameter is `srv_func` and the type of the parameter is `bool(T::*)(MReq &, MRes &)`. That type is pointer to non-static member function of class type `T` that returns `bool` and has parameters of type `MReq &, MRes &`.